# How to prevent components from rendering in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is there a way to prevent a component from rendering in Flex (to save memory or processing power)?

I tried doing something like:

```
<components:AddNewItemGroup id="addItemGroup" 
            visible="false"
            enabled="false"
            horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0" />
```

I noticed that the component gets rendered but it's just not visible or functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent a component from being rendered, you need to remove it from the display list using the `removeChild` method in Actionscript.

Comment: I tried the following: AS: itemsGroupContainer.removeChild(addItemGroup); MXML: <s:Group id="itemsGroupContainer"><components:AddNewItemGroup id="addItemGroup" horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0" /></s:Group> But it didn't seem to work! Also where should I put the ActionScript code? if I put it in 'creationComplete' event of the component it wouldn't do what I want as it will render the item and then remove it.

Comment: ended up using addElement instead and it seems to work as opposed to addChild maybe it's because I'm using Flex 4

Answer (score 0):

How about setting "includeInLayout='false'" too ? The doc says it will not draw the component ... but maybe it will still "render" it ...

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_4.html

Comment: Setting that to false will still render the component:

`If false, the object is positioned by its parent container as per its layout rules, but it is ignored for the purpose of computing the position of the next child.`

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#includeInLayout

Comment: I agree, I was wondering about the combination of both visible=false and includeInLayout=false.

Answer (score 0):

For the desired effect, use:

<components:AddNewItemGroup 
            id="addItemGroup" 
            **visible="false"
            includeInLayout="false"**
            enabled="false"
            horizontalCenter="0" bottom="0" />